# How to harmonize text positioning in different browsers?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask if there is a solution to tackle browser inconsistencies when it comes to text positioning (vertical offsets). With just a few px, the differences are small and not a big problem if there is enough space around the text. But when there is a visual border near the text, different distances to the top and bottom can be annoying.

Here is an example with screenshots from various browsers: 
[image]

Relevant CSS:

```
div {
  padding: 0;
  font: bold 2em/1 Tahoma;
}
```

(Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwQemQ)

The differences depend on the font which is being used. In this example, it's only 1 px with Tahoma, but with other fonts, like Helvetica on OS X, the offset is bigger. Is there a solution (apart from browser sniffing) for this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Using some external font I think, like Lato.

Comment: ever thought of this here: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/